# ClickOnce not launching

Tags: .net, clickonce

I've got a user that is not able to launch our ClickOnce application (there are thousands of users that can just fine). They are not receiving any errors nor does the ClickOnce installation dialog display. The only thing that happens when they click the button to launch it is a progress bar shows up in the bottom of the screen saying that it is downloading the url.

The application is .Net 2.0 (I don't reference any of the 3.x assemblies). The user has Windows Vista and IE8. I checked the ClickOnce cache and it is empty (no applications at all). What else should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the user has the necessary permissions to install ClickOnce applications (although I would imagine that would throw an error).  If this is a computer on the domain, login as a different user and see if they can install the ClickOnce application.

Comment: It does seem to be a permissions issue. I ran IE as admin and it worked. This isn't happening for anybody else that I'm aware of. What permissions should I look at?

Comment: Here's the MSDN version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx  But the short answer is, it kinda depends on where the application is being installed from.  If the user is installing it via the web, you need to check their Internet Zone settings in IE, have you tried/is it possible to install it from a network location instead?

Comment: It is deployed over the Internet and it wouldn't be possible to run it from a network share. I did add our domain to the list of safe sites and that still didn't help. As a note, I also was not able to get the Google Chrome ClickOnce installer to run on his machine.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in the cache, that means, it has not been downloaded.  I'd check the following:

- Does the user have some type of 3rd party firewall installed?
- Try a different ClickOnce app.  For instance, Google Chrome installer is a ClickOnce app.

Comment: Chrome doesn't install either. It seems to be a permission issue, but I'm not sure what the permission is that is missing.

Comment: @bbrewder.  I am going to have to say that it's an IE issue.  Try doing the same from Firefox.  Make sure that Firefox has the ClickOnce plugin installed (either the 3rd party one or the one that comes with .NET 3.5)  If that still does not work, get Process Monitor from live.sysinternals.com and you can see what is being denied.  There is a bit of a learning curve with the tool, but nothing horrible.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce creates a log of all installations.  By default this is stored in temporary internet files, but you can change this location.  Doing this should allow you to see what ClickOnce is doing and where it is having issues.  This may help you determine the root cause.

Here is a link to MSDN on how to change the ClickOnce log location:
[Change ClickOnce log location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404265.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you have to look at the security settings for the browser. Did you try loading it in other browsers other than IE. Firefox should be able to prompt you to download the .application file.  Try adding the site to the trusted sites Through tools->internet options->security->trusted sites and add your url there and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it was a quick blink message of `Application downloading to 100%` at the bottom of IE, but after that nothing happens. There was no usual pop-up dialog box that tells you that the application is checking requirements before it will run on your machine.

Sometimes the quick blink message at the bottom of IE is `Running Scan`, but it will disappear quickly, and nothing happens.

Here's what works for me:

- I run my Internet Explorer as Administrator and now it did launch my click-once application successfully.

Another way to fix this on my case:

- I also noticed that I am running Internet Explorer on different instance or window. This is not on a different tab but rather on a different IE instance. So what I did, I close all running instance of IE and double check on Task Manager if all IE process were terminated then run the click once app URL and it now works.

It's also a good point to delete your temporary files before doing the steps above so that you will get a fresh install of your application and to prevent some minor issues. This can be found at, and delete all your folders **under 2.0 folder**:

```
C:\Users\{youraccount}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0
```